# Playwright projects are not run in parallel

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

As per Playwright v1.36 [documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-projects#running-sequence), the projects are run in parallel.

My `playwright.config.ts`, with number of workers set to 2, contains five projects (including setup) in the following `playwright.config.ts` file:

```
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';
import Variables from './common/variables';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { TestOptions } from './fixtures/configs.fixture';
import { ConfigVersion } from './common/enums/configuration.version.enum';
/**
 * Read environment variables from file.
 * https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv
 */
dotenv.config();

/**
 * See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration.
 */
export default defineConfig<TestOptions>({
  // Look for test files in the directory relative to this configuration file.
  testDir: './tests',
  // Maximum time [ms] each test runs before timeout.
  timeout: 60_000,
  /* set the maximum number of parallel workers */
  workers: Variables.ci ? 2 : 1,
  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: Variables.ci,
  /* Retry on CI only */
  retries: Variables.ci ? 1 : 0,
  /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
  reporter: Variables.ci ? [['list'], ['junit', { outputFile: 'test-results/results.xml' }]] : [['list', { printSteps: true }]],
  /* Global setup path */
  globalSetup: './global-setup/global-setup',
  /* Shared settings for all the assertions */ 
  expect: {
    // Maximum time [ms] expect() should wait for the condition to be met.
    timeout: 30_000,
  },
  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  use: {
    /* Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`. */
    baseURL: Variables.baseUrl,
    headless: Variables.ci,
    // Set custom test id attribute from @playwright/test config:
    testIdAttribute: 'data-test-id',
    /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
    trace: 'retain-on-failure',
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure'
  },
  projects: [
    { 
      name: 'setup', 
      testMatch: '**/*.setup.ts'
    },
    {
      name: 'firefox, config v1',
      dependencies: ['setup'],
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Firefox'],
        storageState: './.auth/user.json',
        viewport: {width: 1920, height: 912},
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'firefox, config v2',
      dependencies: ['setup'],
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Firefox'],
        storageState: './.auth/user.json',
        viewport: {width: 1920, height: 912},
        configVersion: ConfigVersion.V2
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'chromium, config v2',
      dependencies: ['setup'],
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        storageState: './.auth/user.json',
        viewport: {width: 1920, height: 912},
        configVersion: ConfigVersion.V2
      },
    },
    { 
      name: 'chromium, config v1',
      dependencies: ['setup'],
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        storageState: './.auth/user.json',
        viewport: {width: 1920, height: 912},
      },
    },
  ]
});
```

setup code looks as follows:

```
const authFile = '.auth/user.json';
const username = Variables.username;
const password = Variables.password;


setup('authenticate', async ({ page }) => {
  const navigate = new NavigateAction(page);  
  const login = new LoginAction(page);

  await navigate.toLoginPage();
  const homePage = await login.as(username, password)

  await expect(homePage.nameTile).toBeVisible();

  await page.context().storageState({ path: authFile });
});
```

`setup` should go first, then remaining ones run in parallel.
The case is, they projects are not run in parallel, with test files inside them being run in such manner.
The example is presented in a screenshot below:

[image]

First, `setup` is played, but after that there are tests run in parallel from one project only, instead of two project being run in parallel.

I know that it's possible to run the projects in parallel running separate projects in CI parallely, I wonder if it's possible to do it using Playwright config exclusively though. Maybe there's a thing I've missed in it.

Comment: Please share your setup & config code as well as its relevant.

Comment: Added setup and configuration code

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are not setting  workers as 1 in your config.This will cause the sequential execution.

```
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  workers: 1,  // for sequential execution
  testMatch: 'test.list.ts',
});
```

Note: Keep in mind that a worker is always working on a specific file unless fully-parallel is enabled. In your case it depends how many files you have, if you have 3 files per project and 3 workers, then it will run the 3 files in parallel with the required browsers.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to add the information, editing the post right now. I have workers number set to 2. As shown in the screenshot, there are two tests running at once.

Comment: Then , it is what expected.Increase the workers to higher count , better be more than number of projects.

Comment: It's not helpful at all, as number of files containing tests is greater than number of projects.

Answer (score 0):

I raised an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/26367) in Playwright github and received a reply.
Works as designed, some changes in documentation are to be introduced to avoid confusion.